# list index out of range in Openpyxl related to Style while loading workbook

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to load the workbook, I can't read this specific file.

```
input_workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(input_file)
```

Error i'm receiving is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin/Development/pythonProject/venv/RFQ_Analysis_R01.py", line 121, in <module>
    input_workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(input_file)
  File "/home/admin/Development/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "/home/admin/Development/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 280, in read
    self.read_worksheets()
  File "/home/admin/Development/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 228, in read_worksheets
    ws_parser.bind_all()
  File "/home/admin/Development/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_reader.py", line 434, in bind_all
    self.bind_cells()
  File "/home/admin/Development/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_reader.py", line 339, in bind_cells
    style = self.ws.parent._cell_styles[cell['style_id']]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: The exception is very clear: there is a problem with your file.

Comment: I tried with Pandas, it can read. But this happens with only Openpyxl library.

Comment: I've run into the same issue. The Excel file loads perfectly in Excel, but it breaks with openpyxl.

Answer (score 4):

I've run into the same issue. It does not appear to be an issue with the file format, as the file opens just fine in Excel. This just looks like it's a bug with `openpyxl`. (I've [opened a issue request here](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1673))

You can workaround it with the following monkey patch. Just put it into your startup code somewhere.

```
def monkey_patch_openpyxl():
    '''Openpyxl has a bug with workbooks that have wrong cell styling information.
    Monkey patch the library so it can handle these types of workbooks.'''
    from openpyxl.worksheet import _reader
    from openpyxl.cell import Cell
    def bind_cells(self):
        for idx, row in self.parser.parse():
            for cell in row:
                try:
                    style = self.ws.parent._cell_styles[cell['style_id']]
                except:  ## This is the patch, original doesn't have a try/except here
                    style = None
                c = Cell(self.ws, row=cell['row'], column=cell['column'], style_array=style)
                c._value = cell['value']
                c.data_type = cell['data_type']
                self.ws._cells[(cell['row'], cell['column'])] = c
        self.ws.formula_attributes = self.parser.array_formulae
        if self.ws._cells:
            self.ws._current_row = self.ws.max_row # use cells not row dimensions

    _reader.WorksheetReader.bind_cells = bind_cells

monkey_patch_openpyxl()
```

Comment: That did not appear to fix the issue for me (python version 3.6; openpyxl.__version__ == '3.0.9').

Comment: I get error 
    `self.ws.formula_attributes = self.parser.array_formulae
AttributeError: 'WorkSheetParser' object has no attribute 'array_formulae'. Did you mean: 'parse_formula'?` (openpyxl version: 3.1.2)

Answer (score 0):

tldr - if you are using `XlsxWriter` make sure you are not writing `None` as the format for a cell.

---

I ran in to this while generating a simple xlsx file while using [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/index.html). The xlsx files always opened fine but failed to load with `openpyxl`

Turns out I had a helper function like this

```
def writerow(worksheet, row, cols, fmt=None):
  for i, val in enumerate(cols):
    worksheet.write(r, i, val, fmt)
```

If you notice I was essentially calling `worksheet.write(r, i, val, None)` when I did not explicitly pass a format.

The fix is to just make sure you always have a format when you are writing a row.

```
default_format = workbook.add_format()
worksheet.write(row, col, value, default_format)
```

Comment: “If you are using XlsxWriter make sure you are not writing None as the format for a cell“. That doesn’t sound right. It is perfectly valid to use None as a format in XlsxWriter `worksheet.write()` and if you do it will create a file exactly like Excel would in the same condition.

Comment: This is in the context of making `openpyxl` happy with `XlsxWriter` based on the https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1673. I had no problems opening it in excel just with `openpyxl`

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem and this is my solution:
Go to the _reader.py (.\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet)

Find the `bind_row_dimensions()` in class `WorksheetReader` and simply apply `try/except` like as:

```
def bind_row_dimensions(self):
    for row, rd in self.parser.row_dimensions.items():
        if 's' in rd:
            key = int(rd['s'])
            try: rd['s'] = self.ws.parent._cell_styles[key]
            except: rd['s'] = None
        self.ws.row_dimensions[int(row)] = RowDimension(self.ws, **rd)
```

It works for me and hope you so.

Comment: do you have a document?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's wrong with your excel file and I also didn't meet the same problem but just try this one, I believe it will work well:

Go to the _reader.py
(.\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet)

Find the `bind_cells()` in class `WorksheetReader` and simply apply try/except like as:

```
 def bind_cells(self):
    for idx, row in self.parser.parse():
        for cell in row:                
            try: style = self.ws.parent._cell_styles[cell['style_id']]
            except: style = StyleArray('i', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
            c = Cell(self.ws, row=cell['row'], column=cell['column'], style_array=style)
            c._value = cell['value']
            c.data_type = cell['data_type']
            self.ws._cells[(cell['row'], cell['column'])] = c

    if self.ws._cells:
        self.ws._current_row = self.ws.max_row # use cells not row dimensions
```